# Sampling from within Pandas groups with defined probabilities

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following Pandas dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
         ['X', 0, 0.5],
         ['X', 1, 0.5],

         ['Y', 0, 0.25],
         ['Y', 1, 0.3],
         ['Y', 2, 0.45],

         ['Z', 0, 0.6],
         ['Z', 1, 0.1],
         ['Z', 2, 0.3]
    ], columns=['NAME', 'POSITION', 'PROB'])
```

Notice that `df` defines a discrete probability distribution for each unique `NAME` value i.e.

```
assert ((df.groupby('NAME')['PROB'].sum() - 1)**2 < 1e-10).all()
```

What I would like to do is sample from these probability distributions.

We can think of `POSITION` as being the values corresponding to the probabilities. So when considering `X` the sample will be `0` with probability `0.5` and `1` with probability `0.5`.

I would like to create a new dataframe with columns `['NAME', 'POSITION', 'PROB', 'SAMPLE']` representing these samples. Each unique `SAMPLE` value represents a new sample. The `PROB` column is now always 0 or 1, representing whether the given row was selected in the given sample. For example, if I were to select 3 samples an example outcome is below,

```
df_samples = pd.DataFrame(
    [
         ['X', 0, 1, 0],
         ['X', 1, 0, 0],
         ['X', 0, 0, 1],
         ['X', 1, 1, 1],
         ['X', 0, 1, 2],
         ['X', 1, 0, 2],

         ['Y', 0, 1, 0],
         ['Y', 1, 0, 0],
         ['Y', 2, 0, 0],
         ['Y', 0, 0, 1],
         ['Y', 1, 0, 1],
         ['Y', 2, 1, 1],
         ['Y', 0, 1, 2],
         ['Y', 1, 0, 2],
         ['Y', 2, 0, 2],

         ['Z', 0, 0, 0],
         ['Z', 1, 0, 0],
         ['Z', 2, 1, 0],
         ['Z', 0, 0, 1],
         ['Z', 1, 0, 1],
         ['Z', 2, 1, 1],
         ['Z', 0, 1, 2],
         ['Z', 1, 0, 2],
         ['Z', 2, 0, 2],
    ], columns=['NAME', 'POSITION', 'PROB', 'SAMPLE'])
```

Of course due to the randomness involved, this is just one of a number of possible outcomes.

A unittest for the program would be that as the samples increases, by the law of large numbers, the mean number of our samples for each `(NAME, POSITION)` pair, should tend to the actual probability. One could calculate a confidence region based on the total samples used and then make sure the true probability lies within it. For example using a [normal approximation to binomial outcomes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_proportion_confidence_interval) (requires total samples `n_samples` to be 'large') a (-4 sd, 4 sd) region test would be:

```
z = 4

p_est = df_samples.groupby(['NAME', 'POSITION'])['PROB'].mean()
p_true = df.set_index(['NAME', 'POSITION'])['PROB']

CI_lower = p_est - z*np.sqrt(p_est*(1-p_est)/n_samples)
CI_upper = p_est + z*np.sqrt(p_est*(1-p_est)/n_samples)

assert p_true < CI_upper
assert p_true > CI_lower
```

What is the most efficient way to do this in Pandas? I feel like I want to apply some `sample` function to the `df.groupby('NAME')` object.

**P.S.**

To be even more explicit, here is a very long winded way of doing this using Numpy.

```
n_samples = 3
df_list = []
for name in ['X', 'Y', 'Z']:
    idx = df['NAME'] == name
    position_samples = np.random.choice(df.loc[idx, 'POSITION'], 
                                        n_samples, 
                                        p=df.loc[idx, 'PROB'])
    prob = np.zeros([idx.sum(), n_samples])
    prob[position_samples, np.arange(n_samples)] = 1
    position = np.tile(np.arange(idx.sum())[:, None], n_samples)
    sample = np.tile(np.arange(n_samples)[:,None], idx.sum()).T

    df_list.append(pd.DataFrame(
        [[name, prob.ravel()[i], position.ravel()[i], 
          sample.ravel()[i]] 
         for i in range(n_samples*idx.sum())], 
        columns=['NAME', 'PROB', 'POSITION', 'SAMPLE']))

df_samples = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Comment: There is a way to do stuff like this.  The problem is your question.  You state "The easiest way to explain..."  I disagree.  I'd like to see a better explanation.

Comment: What are you confused about?

Comment: @rwolst, I don't understand any of your question, unfortunately. Maybe it's me, but maybe it's not. You might want to [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50330090/edit) with detail of your logic.

Comment: What does "If I were to select 3 samples" mean?  You mention probability but didn't provide your desired probability.  You can have an infinite variety of probabilities that all generate that specific combined 3 samples.  I don't understand if you want a mechanism for generating 3 samples or 1 sample.  It is best to read [mcve] and edit your post accordingly.

Comment: Its probably me. I will edit when I get to a computer.

Comment: IIUC, the question means this: given a distribution for `GROUP`, generate 3 triplets, one per support element in the distribution, distributed according to `PROB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for `groupby` + [`sample`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sample.html) and then some indexing stuff

First sample by the probabilites:

```
n_samples = 3
df_samples = df.groupby('NAME').apply(lambda x: x[['NAME', 'POSITION']] \
                               .sample(n_samples, replace=True,
                                       weights=x.PROB)) \
                               .reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now add the extra columns:

```
df_samples['SAMPLE'] = df_samples.groupby('NAME').cumcount()
df_samples['PROB'] = 1


print(df_samples)

  NAME  POSITION  SAMPLE  PROB
0    X         1       0     1
1    X         0       1     1
2    X         1       2     1
3    Y         1       0     1
4    Y         1       1     1
5    Y         1       2     1
6    Z         2       0     1
7    Z         0       1     1
8    Z         0       2     1
```

Note that this doesn't include the 0 probability positions for each sample as requested in the initial question but it is a more concise way of storing the information.

If we want to also include the 0 probability positions we can merge in the other positions as follows:

```
domain = df[['NAME', 'POSITION']].drop_duplicates()
df_samples.drop('PROB', axis=1, inplace=True)
df_samples = pd.merge(df_samples, domain, on='NAME', 
                      suffixes=['_sample', ''])
df_samples['PROB'] = (df_samples['POSITION'] ==
                     df_samples['POSITION_sample']).astype(int)
df_samples.drop('POSITION_sample', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: This seems very close and certainly the sample function looks to be what I want. I have edited the answer to put it in the same format as the output I requested. It still as mentioned, doesn't include the 0 probability positions at each sample. After thinking about it however its not a big issue at all.

Comment: Added a final merge that gives the desired output but more than happy for someone better than me with Pandas to clean up the code.